# Make input text field full width inside table cell

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/p1my39fh/

```css
table {
    width: 550px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #A4A4A4;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0;
}
table td {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="30"/></td>
        <td>Test Information</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I remove the space around the `<input>`?

How can I make both `<td>`s to be the same width?

Comment: why  don't you set the width of td to 275px, since you have a fixed width?

Comment: Set the input to width: 100%.

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work, however, I just tried again and it did work.  Thanks.  (I feel dumb) (regarding the width to 275px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was:

why don't you set the width of td to 275px, since you have a fixed width? –  jp-jee Jun 11 at 16:43

That comment.

Setting the width to a fixed length worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

To make both `<td>` cells to have same width, you could set:

```
table {
    width: 550px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

To have the `<input>` field to fill the entire width of the `<td>` cell, you could set:

```
input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Updated demo:**

```css
table {
    width: 550px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #A4A4A4;
    border: 2px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
td input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="30"/></td>
        <td>Test Information</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 10):

you add width:50%; into table td and expand input width to get rid of space around input

```
table td input {
 width: 100%;   
}
```